# Module structure for $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, modules

I am interested to know which module structures we can define in the additive group of integers $\mathbb{Z}$.

It is easy to prove that $\mathbb{Z}$ does not admit a vector space structure. (For more details see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151850/prove-mathbbz-is-not-a-vector-space-over-a-field.)

My question is: is there any characterization of the associative rings with identity $R$ such that $\mathbb{Z}$ admits an $R$-module structure, and also, can we describe how are these structures?

**Some remarks:**

1. It is clear that $R$ must have characteristic zero, since if $R$ had characteristic $n \neq 0$, then we would have $n = 1 + \cdots + 1 = 1_{R}1 + \cdots +1_{R}1 = (1_{R} + \cdots + 1_{R})1 = 0$, a contradiction.
2. To give a $R$-module structure for $\mathbb{Z}$ is equivalent to give a ring homomorphism $R \rightarrow \text{End}(\mathbb{Z}) \simeq \mathbb{Z}$, hence an $R$-module structure for $\mathbb{Z}$ is equivalent to a ring homomorphism $R \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$. Therefore, my question is equivalent to "in the category of associative rings with identity, is there a description for $\text{Hom}(R,\mathbb{Z})$?". (This is an interesting reformulation since we know that $\mathbb{Z}$ is the initial object in this category, but not terminal.)

Comment: Every such homomorphism factors through $R/I$, where $I$ is the intersection of all kernel of homomorphisms $R\to\mathbf{Z}$. Hence we can boil down to the case when $I=\{0\}$, in which case, in particular, $R$ is commutative (and isomorphic to a subring of $\mathbf{Z}^X$ for some some set $X$).

Comment: BTW you're asking two distinct questions, one being "is $\mathrm{Hom}(R,\mathbf{Z})$ non-empty?" and the other is "can one describe $\mathrm{Hom}(R,\mathbf{Z})$?" which is probably more interesting and of course encompasses the first question (clearly it's empty if $R$ is a field, or has finite characteristic, etc.).

Comment: @YCor thank you, I will edit the question.

Comment: This can be viewed as asking which rings are augmented over $\mathbb Z$.  For example any group or monoid ring is.   Monoids often have several natural augmentations.  One for each (completely) prime ideal.

Comment: For $R$ a (commutative) ring of *finite type* (over $\mathbf Z$), determining algorithmically whether $R$ has a $\mathbf Z$-point is impossible by the negative solution to Hilbert's 10th problem. (More generally, I think it's fair to say that determining which finite type $\mathbf Z$-algebras have $\mathbf Z$-points is one of the central questions of number theory.)